# How to get rid of a Google contact in your chatting list?

Tags: google-contacts

I have a gmail contact which I don't want them to see me online - but I still want the others contact see me online. A feature similar to stealth setting in Yahoo. How can I do that with gmail/gtalk?

**[Edit]**
Thanks to help from user, [blocking user as offically said here](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57686) is the answered.

> Blocking someone will prevent him or
>   her from talking to you, and
>   vice-versa. Blocked users can't see
>   when you're signed in to Google Talk,
>   and you won't see their status in your
>   Friends list, either. If you decide
>   you'd like to communicate with someone
>   you've blocked, just unblock them.

Comment: I guess you don't want to see *them* online..

Comment: @Lipis I believe you're misunderstanding the question... He doesn't want them to see him online.  @user5821 is right, Blocking them is the only answer.

Comment: You don't edit the answer into the question, you either select from the other answers or you post it if it's not there.

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise: I add the refined and complete answer so as you and any other users can easily find it - otherwise, people will have to seek for the answer combined from 1 answer and 2 comments which lie somewhere below! If it is useless, I have removed it. StackExchange is a place for asking, sharing, and blogging isn't it?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the "Video & More" drop down when you hover over the contact, then select "Block". You will always appear in their list as offline.

(Edit: In Google Talk, hover over the contact and you get a down arrow. Click "Block (name)".)

Comment: I would say instead of block, Nam Gi VU wants the Always hide option

Comment: Possible, but I interpreted his question to mean that he wanted his online status to be hidden from a particular contact. If he selects "always hide", that contact will not appear in Nam's contact list, but the "hidden" contact will still be able to see Nam's online status - and send him IMs.

Comment: @user5821: Since the message Google gives out after I blocked a contact is something similar like "You won't recieve any more message from the blocked contact", I'm not sure I'm visible to him/her. Can you put a official reference from Google about this?

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57686